# How to restart/reuse a recurring Task?

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library

I have a long-running Task that I've implemented using the Task Parallel Library.  When the Task starts, I grab snapshots of several input values and collections then perform various operations using that information.  If any of those values or collections change while the Task is running, I'd like to have the Task run again immediately upon completion.  Should I be creating a new Task or is there a way to reuse the existing Task?  What's the best way to start the second iteration?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Create a new task.

As http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270682.aspx points out, trying to restart a running or completed Task is not supported. It is rarely a good idea to do something that normally throws an exception, and re-using a Task is one of those things.

Comment: How would you signal the need for the second task? Changes could occur while the original task is running or not until sometime after it has completed.

Comment: Based on that criteria, I think you would do fine with a single, non-terminating Task that polls the current state, and if the state changes, do your thing. The basic requirement here is that this happens asynchronously, to avoid blocking the main thread. You would need to place a flag of some sort to indicate to the Task that the application is closing and it should terminate.

Comment: A single, non-terminating Task is what I was thinking. I can use a CancellationToken to handle when the app is closing but I'm not sure what mechanism I should use to flag that I need the Task to execute my algorithms. If I use an AutoResetEvent, then I won't be able to cancel because the Task's thread will be suspended waiting for the event. On the other hand, I am reading that using SpinWait is very CPU intensive.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you could use Sleep instead of SpinWait. You could poll every minute, second, etc. and sleep in between e.g. `while (continue()) if (ready()) do_whatever(); else sleep();`

Answer (score 1):

You can't start again an existing `Task`. So you have two options:

1. Start a new `Task`. This is probably cleaner.
2. Run an loop in your `Task` that checks whether something changed since the last time and if it does, starts a new iteration.

Comment: Same question as above: How would you signal the need for the second task?

Comment: Hard to tell without knowing how do you determine that the second task is needed. If you want to restart even after it has completed, you might use events.

Answer (score 0):

You could also refactor program logic to use function pointers (or delegates in VB.NET).