# Why are Task objects not reusable?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466212/how-to-restart-reuse-a-recurring-task) leads me to another more general (and probably fundamental) question, Why are `Task` objects not reusable?

Microsoft writes this statement without explanation:

> A task may only be started and run only once. Any attempts to schedule
>   a task a second time will result in an exception.

Is the reasoning behind this so obvious that it deserves no explanation? Is there no performance hit for repeatedly setting and starting a `Task` with a Continuation?

Comment: `Task` represents a single invocation of the passed delegate; it's not reusable because it's meant to represent something done once. The delegate, however, is free to be reused how ever many times you want, because it represents the thing to be done, and not any particular execution of that thing.

Comment: When we use a `Task` to wrap an `Event` are we running into the danger of failing to understand the single-use nature of a `Task`?

Comment: @rasx, what do you mean by a `Task` wrapping an `Event`?

Comment: @rasx When you use a `Task` to wrap an event you're saying that this task represents the *next* time that the event is invoke, not that it represents that event as a whole, or every time it is invoked.  To do the latter you can use an `IObservable` which *can* represent every single invocation of that event.

Comment: @MattSmith The common patter of using a `TaskCompletionSource` to create a task that will be completed the next time an event is fired.

Comment: @MattSmith Stephen Toub shows this wrapping technique in his last build talk: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2013/3-301

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `Task` is a representation of *a single* something that might happen at some point in the future.  It provides means of indicating publicly when the task is done, if it's done, what the final state of that task was, etc.

After a task has finished and you start it up again what should the `IsCompleted` property return?  It did complete, but you started it up again.  Are you saying that the caller should only have the ability to access the final state (i.e. whether it was canceled, it's exceptions, it's `Result`, etc.) for the window of time after it is started and before it is completed?  That would be highly confusing.

There are other objects out there that can represent an operation being repeated, or some collection of asynchronous operations, such as (among other options) `IObservable`, which is effectively an asynchronous *sequence* that could (potentially) represent the results of N calls to a particular delegated, called sequentially.

Comment: I think I am learning about the difference between reuse and reconstructing the conditions in order to run a single something once. I also feel that I am stumbling upon the theoretical origins of ReactiveUI: http://www.reactiveui.net/ ...when we say that something is meant to run *once* the implication can be once for all time---but what it actually could be is once within a time slice of some domain-specific life cycle.