# Can Task be reused?

Tags: c#, .net

Let's say I have something like this:

```
Task task0_1 = new Task(() => CopyFiles(now, Offset, true));
Task task0_2 = new Task(() => CopyFiles(now, Offset, true));
task0_1.Start();
task0_2.Start();
Task.WaitAll(task0_1, task0_2);

task0_1 = new Task(() => CopyFiles(0, 0, false));
task0_2 = new Task(() => CopyFiles(0, 0, false));
```

As you can see, once both tasks have completed (after `Task.WaitAll`) I call `CopyFiles` once again the same way by reusing `task0_1` and `task0_2`, but with different parameters.

Would it be wise to reuse these tasks? The project builds, but I'm not sure how 'correct' this is.

Comment: You're not reusing the task, you're reusing the variable as a reference to a newly created task. That is fine, while actually reusing the same task is fine as well.

Comment: In your example, `Task` is not being re-used; rather, the variables are being re-used and assigned a new `Task`.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

In my opinion, nothing wrong to reuse the `Task` as it is basically a class.

In MSDN:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx

```
[HostProtectionAttribute(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, Synchronization = true, 
    ExternalThreading = true)]
public class Task : IAsyncResult, IDisposable
```

From the code above, `Task` is a class that implement interfaces.

So, to answer your question, yes, you can reuse it cause it's a class and because it's a class, it is basically a reference to the object created.

Comment: Task can not be reused. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466212/how-to-restart-reuse-a-recurring-task

Answer (score 1):

`task0_1` is a variable and like any  other variable type you can re-use it  while this will let the code readable and maintainable which is your case since you are using `Task.WaitAll` but be careful as you are loosing asynchronous  aspect of task when you use `Task.WaitAll`
here an example

```
 Task task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine( "task1" +i);
                    }
                });
            Task task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("task2" + i);
                }
            });
            Task.WaitAll(task1, task2); 
            Console.WriteLine("hi I'm Here "); // hi  im here will not printed until the others 2 tasks has finished so beaware of this on UI 
            Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score -1):

From variable naming point of view I wouldn't suggest to reuse same variable for different objects because it is a good practice to name your variables so you would describe your object and things like that might be very confusing:

```
var dog = new Mammal(Mammals.Dog);

//some code

dog = new Mammal(Mammals.Cat);

// dog actually is a cat
```

However if you don't care about readability there is nothing wrong with your approach.